# How to create an object of a class where the constructor takes arguments as objects of other classes

Tags: java, object

I am a beginner in java. I recently came across this situation.

Suppose we have a class `C`.

```java
public class C {
    C(A a, B b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    }
  A a;
  B b;

 ....

  }
```

Where a, b are objects of classes `A` and `B` respectively.

```java
public class A {
 ....
  }
```

```java
public class B {
 ....
  }
```

So how do I create an object of type `C` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an instance of `A` and `B` to pass into the constructor of `C`. Something like this, assuming `A` and `B` have empty constructors:

```java
A aObj = new A();
B bObj = new B();
C cObj = new C(aObj, bObj);
```

The `cObj` object's `a` and `b` fields will be references to the `aObj` and `bObj` instances that are constructed and passed in.